# Why aren't we building and using parallel processors *meant* for general computation?

Tags: programming-languages, performance, language-agnostic, multithreading

We all know GPUs are much faster than CPUs for a wide range of applications. When someone asks why we are not just programming for GPUs at all, one of the most common answers is that GPUs are not good for everything - i.e., they fail to do some things that CPUs do easily. Well, no wonder: after all, they are not **meant to be used for general computations**. GPUs are strongly tied to games and graphical applications, not only having specialized functions for those, but often being advertised for them.

My question is: why, then, aren't we building and using processors that are **actually designed for parallel programs**?

Comment: What non-game applications would consumers actually use them for?

Comment: We are: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xeon_Phi, for example. As Telastyn suggests ordinary consumers just don't have much use for them.

Comment: I beg to differ with @Telastyn and Charles E. Grant.  Any consumer with an up to date iPhone (I guess other recent smartphones too) is using a multi-core (parallel) processor.  Surely they're not all playing games with them ?

Comment: Maybe not an average consumer, but I'm programming a computing server for a specific application and the benefit of having an actual parallel computer I could program into would be immeasurable.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - There's a difference between having 8-16 processors that use your normal instruction set and can do stuff for you concurrently and thousands of processors that run together over vectorized data using a entirely different instruction set (though language support has vastly improved).

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, well sure, but there we're talking about 2-6 cores. GPU and systems like the phi use thousands of cores simultaneously.

Comment: Last time it did not work: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transputer

Comment: Your title and the question in the body are in conflict: please edit.

Comment: But is your task on the server CPU bound or IO bound? Having many processors won't help your throughput much if all of the processors are twiddling their thumbs waiting for the network or the disk to respond.

Comment: Processors designed for parallel programs have been around for more than 40 years.  The IBM 2938 (introduced in 1968) and 3838 (1974) are two examples.

Answer (score 13):

We already do; that's what [multi-core processors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor) are for.

Part of highly-optimizing for speed is specialization.  When you build processors that specialize in one thing, you can optimize for that one thing, and ignore optimizing for anything else.

Optimization can have conflicting goals.  That's the reason we have many different kinds of data structures; each is optimized for a specific task.  If you could write a data structure that was fully optimized for *any* task, then we'd all be using only that data structure, and nothing else.

Answer (score 11):

Because general computation is hard to parallelize into the [SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) model that is the driving force behind GPU design. Graphics has the bonus of having each vertex of the rendered mesh being able to be looked at in isolation and execute the same operations on it to figure out it's position on the screen and with each resulting pixel on screen is the same. Those are the basis for the vertex and fragment shader in openGL.

General computation is harder to get kernelized computation units that are worth it to parallelize in this way.

Having said that supercomputers are heavily parallelized with each core being a full CPU (using the more flexible [MIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIMD) model) and efficient communication between each core.

Efficient parallelization is an open research area with several books written about them.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers are good, but the question reminds me of a past phenomenon in computer graphics (remember that?)

It was called the [*Wheel of Reincarnation*](http://www.cap-lore.com/Hardware/Wheel.html).
It goes like this:

1. Invent a computer.
2. Program the computer to do something useful, like draw pictures.
3. For performance, invent a special processor to off-load the picture drawing.
4. To improve the special processor, make it more "intelligent" like a computer.
5. Now even more of the work can be offloaded to the special processor.
6. Voila', we're back at 1. !

This is still going on, with GPUs, with ever "smarter" browsers, etc.
It seems to happen whenever there's a communication bottleneck between processors, and the redundancy due to separation of responsibilities leads to maintainability problems.

---

Not to brag (*aw, go ahead* ) I tried to short-circuit this cycle ages ago by a scheme that automatically manages a remote client without requiring extra code to be written.
I called it [*differential execution*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24875909/23771).

The relevance to the current question is that the advantage of having multiple processors adapted to different parts of the job is offset by the need to write separate programs for them, which then produces bugs, rather than just saying what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Parallel programming(multi-threaded) is hard. Orders of magnitudes harder then single-threaded programming.

Yes, you can get more performance, but this performance comes at a cost: developer time. And developer time is most often more costly then a program that's optimized a bit less but is finished sooner.

Comment: Parallel programming ≠ multi-threaded. E.g. Actor Model.